# How can I make subfolder domain alias?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, plesk

Sorry for my bad english.

What I want is this;

```
domain.com - a Software
domain.com/subfolder/ - another Software
anothersoftware.com - Domain alias for domain.com/subfolder/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most convenient way is .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder http:/anothersoftware.com/
```